# What are the isomers of a complex having a structure of M(AB)2C2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

Our instructor have us answer an isomerism problem of a crystal structure that has a form of $\ce{M(AB)2C2}$. I keep getting 9 isomers, which includes the optically inactive isomer, and my peers and I have different answers.

Comment: I thought of several wrong ways to count isomers, and still failed to get 5. If you want us to tell which of your isomers is wrong or which one is missing, then we really need to know more.

Comment: After more fiddling I succeeded in getting 5. If your peers are getting more, they must be counting enantiomers.

Comment: Sorry, but I have noticed that 4 of my isomers have D and L forms so instead of 5, the isomers that I have is 9 including the one which is the optically inactive isomer.

Comment: Great. (Or maybe not.) Now you are ahead of me, because I'm getting 8, of which two are optically inactive.

Comment: How did you form another optically inactive isomer? I am new to this topic that's why I can't trust my intuitions.

Comment: By morphing together two of your supposedly optically active isomers which are in fact the same, that's how. Look again at those which have their C ligands in _trans_ position to each other.

Comment: I see what you mean but from what i see, there is no plane of symmetry in the complex.

Comment: Yes there is. It passes through all A's and B's.

Comment: Is it possible? The tutorial video that i've watched on youtube said that the ligands that passes through all A's and B's can't have a mirror plane since they are not in the same plane.

Comment: In my book they are. Do we really have the same picture before our eyes? Look again at the isomer(s) in question. Which pairs of ligands are _opposite_?

Comment: You said that I should look at the C ligands that are trans with each other so I did. There is only one complex that I have that has C ligands trans with each other, not counting the complex that has C on the plane of the octahedral geometry. Sidenote, sir may I ask what is the name of the book you are using that contains isomers for a complex with M(AB)2C2 form? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not using any book, it was a figure of speech. OK, maybe you'll add some drawings to your question.

Comment: I see now what you mean sir, thank you! It is indeed the same molecule.

Comment: Great! Now I guess you may write an answer yourself, or just leave it at that and call it a day.

Comment: I will answer my own question and would mention you sir for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Referring to the replies of Mr. Ivan Neretin, complexes that has a form of M(AB)2C2 posses 8 stereoisomers, 2 of which are optically inactive. The other 6 isomers can be interchanged to their respective enantiomers.

Comment: Without some pictures this answer is hardly helpful for other people struggling with the question. It doesn't even specify the coordination of M.

Comment: I tried to at least put a picture of the complex for easier visualization but I failed to generate one.

Comment: Do you have a pen and paper and a camera? This should work fine for starters, someone else might use the chance to produce higher quality images if necessary.

Comment: I don't have any gadgets with me except for this PC that I am using.